# Programmatically change text color of all text that is a specific color in a application? Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

Is there a way to change the color of all the text in my IOS application? we've decided to go with a new color scheme for our app, we've got a bunch of purple text we'd like to make black or gray.

All the text is in the storyboards. I also can't even find the color code that was used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that `[[UILabel appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];` works perfectly. You should use *appearance proxy* for all components you want to change (*UITextView, UITextField and etc*).

Comment: I'll give this a try when I get home. At work currently, I'll let you know if this works.

Comment: You should do the same not only with UILabel but with UITextView, UITextField, and so on

Comment: Probably it is, I just wanted to make it clear, just in case ;)

Comment: Haven't gotten a chance to try this yet, but i'll mark it as the answer since it looks like it should work, I greatly appreciate it!